# Runtime constant pool - is filled up by variables created in runtime?

Tags: java, jvm, pool, string-pool

I'm not sure about some properties of runtime constant pool.

Runtime constant pool, is filled up by the data from constant pool (from .class files, during class loading). But is it also filled up by variables created in runtime? Or are they converted during compilation to literals, and stored in constant pool?

For example:

```
Integer i = new Integer(127);
```

is treated like literal, because of conversion to:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(127);
```

during compilation, and stored in constant pool?

If it's not working like that, is there any runtime mechanics for runtime constant pool?

And second question: I have found this sentence in many articles: "every class got Runtime constant pool", but what does it mean? Is there a single RCP, that contains all application objects of (for example) Integer type, or is there a single RCP for every class, that contains all constant objects, that occured in this class? (for example: Person, got age = Integer(18), and isAdult = Boolean(true)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no conversion of

```
Integer i = new Integer(127);
```

to

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(127);
```

These constructs are entirely different. `new Integer(127)` is guaranteed to produce a new instance every time it is evaluated, whereas `Integer.valueOf(127)` is guaranteed to produce the same instance on every evaluation, as `Integer.valueOf` guarantees for all values in the `-128 … +127` range. This is handled by the implementation of the `Integer.valueOf(int)` and not related to constant pools in any way. Of course, it is implementation specific, but the OpenJDK implementation handles this by simply [filling an array with references to these 256 instance the first time, this cache is accessed](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.IntegerCache).

While it is correct that every class has a [constant pool in its class file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4), it might be misleading to say that every class will have a runtime constant pool (on its own). That’s again a JVM implementation detail. While it is possible to map each class constant pool 1:1 to a runtime constant pool, it obviously makes sense to merge the constant pools of classes living in the same resolve context (i.e. defined by the same class loader) into one pool, so that identical constants don’t need to be resolved multiple times. Though, conceptionally, every class has a runtime representation of its pool, even if they do not materialize in this naive form. So the statement “every class has a runtime constant pool” is not wrong, but it doesn’t necessarily imply that there will be such a data structure for every class.

This affects classes, members, `MethodType`, `MethodHandle` and `String` instances, referenced by the constant pools of the classes, but not wrapper types like `Integer` or `Boolean`, as there are no such entries in a constant pool. Integer values in the pool are primitive values and boolean values do not exist at all.

This must not be confused with the global `String` pool references all `String` instances for literals and the results of [`intern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--) calls.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem 1 - Anwser: No

Integeral wrapper types are *cached*, not *stored in the constant pool*. They are just ordinary objects in the heap. `Integer` or `Byte` caching is a runtime optimization, not a VM optimization, nor a compile time optimization. They are not *magically* replaced with the cached one when their constructor is invoked to create a new one.

First, your translation from `new Integer(127)` to `Integer.valueOf(127)` is not correct at all as explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5277881/). If you do some runtime verifications, like `System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(127) == new Integer(127));` (prints `false`), you will quickly come to the conclusion that no matter what object you are constructing, using `new` operator always creates a new, uncached object. (Even `String`s, who's actually in the runtime constant table, need being interned to get a reference to the canonical one.)

What `i` variable hold is just reference pointing to a `Integer` object in the heap. It will be cached if you are using `valueOf` and vice versa.

---

## Problem 2 - Anwser: There a single RCP for every class but they are all in the same memory region

The [RCPs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.5) are all stored in [method area](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4). Personally I don't know how JVM is implemented, but JVMS has [stated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.1):

> The Java Virtual Machine maintains a per-type constant pool (§2.5.5), a run-time data structure that serves many of the purposes of the symbol table of a conventional programming language implementation.

Nevertheless, this doesn't matter even from a performance tuning view, as long as you don't plan to apply for a job in Oracle.