# What is the output of this code , and why? Please explain to mee

Tags: java, oop

public class test{    //declaring class with name "test"

```
static public void main(String[] args)
{
    Long a=111L;  //declaring Long type variable
    Long b=111L;  //declaring Long type variable
    Long c=222L;  //declaring Long type variable
    Long d=222L;  //declaring Long type variable
    System.out.println((a==b)+" "+(c==d)); /*output is "true false". I dont know Why? Please explain  */
}
```

}

Comment: You know that isn't how you compare objects, right?

Comment: Do you have a specific question, a specific point where you get confused? The code itself is very basic, it just compares some objects and outputs the results of the comparisons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two objects with .equals() and == operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387742/compare-two-objects-with-equals-and-operator)

Comment: *"What is the output of this code?"* Run it and see for yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why aren't Integers cached in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277881/why-arent-integers-cached-in-java)

Comment: You are getting mostly getting downvoted because of the "What is the output of this code" part of the title. It smacks of laziness. You're real quesiton is: Why would 111L == 111L be true, but 222L == 222L be false? which I explain below.

Answer (score 4):

`Long` is a boxed wrapper about the primitive `long`. You should be using `long`.
Primitives are compared with `==`, but objects like a `Long` are compared with `aLong.equals(otherLong)`; otherwise, when you compare with `==` you are comparing for reference equality. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

The reason one might be true and the other false, is because -128 through 127 are cached [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277881/why-arent-integers-cached-in-java%20cached). So any object that is a Long with a value of 111L will be the same object, but a Long with a value of 222L will different from another Long with a value of 222L.

Due to this uncertainty, you should always compare objects with `.equals` unless you specifically want to know if they are the exact same object.

In this case though, I would suggest you use primitives and compare as you are.

Comment: I think you can improve the answer by also linking to some answers on SO where one explained 1) the `equals` and `==` issue and 2) the **autoboxing** stuff.

Comment: Will do @Zabuza

Answer (score 0):

[Java caches the wrapper class(Long) objects instances from the range -128 to 127](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/boxing-and-caches:-integervalueofint-and-friends)

Long variables with the value 111 (cached), the same object instance will be pointed by all references. (N variables, 1 instance)

Long variables with the value 222 (not cached), you will have an object instance pointed by every reference. (N variables, N instances)