# Why can I test inequality of Wrappers like primitives? Can I do it for classes I create?

Tags: java, integer, wrapper, unboxing

In Java, there are wrapper objects which contains just a single primitive type. They are `Integer, Double, Character, Boolean, Byte, Short, Long, Float`, which boxes the `int, double, char, boolean, byte, short, long, float` primitive types respectively.

For most objects, they cannot be compared, but you can implement `Comparable` or `Comparator` so you can define when one object of a given type (call it `Ty`) is less, equal, or greater than another object of the same type `Ty`. However, if so, you test inequality by using `compareTo(Ty oth)` or `compare(Ty arg0, Ty arg1)`, both returning `int`, representing less than if return value < 0, and vice versa.

However, for numeric Wrapper objects (including `Character`), you can actually compare these objects using inequality relational operators for primitives `<, <=, >=, >` as in this code below:

```
Integer a = 15;
Integer b = 0;
Double x = 7.5;
Double y = 15.000000000000000000000000001; // Decimal part discarded
Character ch = 'A';

System.out.println(x + " < " + a + " is " + (x < a));
System.out.println(x + " < " + b + " is " + (x < b));
System.out.println(a + " > " + b + " is " + (a > b));

System.out.println(ch + " <= " + 65 + " is " + (ch <= 64)); // 'A' has ASCII code 65
System.out.println(ch + " <= " + 65 + " is " + (ch <= 65));
System.out.println(a + " >= " + b + " is " + (a >= b));
```

Which outputs

```
7.5 < 15 is true
7.5 < 0 is false
15 > 0 is true
A <= 65 is false
A <= 65 is true
15 >= 0 is true
```

Note that between two objects, `==` and `!=` always work and respectively denote reference equality and inequality instead. It is not part of the question.

**Is "operator overloading" of these wrapper functions unique to the wrappers?**

Comment: The inconsistency between `<=` and `==` is bad enough for the built-in numeric wrappers. Do you really want to introduce that land mine for your own types?

Comment: Can you give me an example of the inconsistency of `<=` and `==`?

Comment: It could cause a NPE if one of the objects are null (as an example)

Comment: https://ideone.com/WxLkig

Comment: Is there any way I can implement the inequality operators as I can in Python? As in `__gt__`, `__ge__`?

Comment: I am meaning specifically for the wrappers. Why can I compare wrappers like primitives?

Comment: Because it would be a pain *not* to be able to. As for how it's possible, it's probably built directly into the language as a corner case just for numeric wrappers. Could be wrong, but either way, comparing primitive wrappers is possible. Allowing your own types to be compared using the less than or greater than operators is not supported.

Comment: The wrapper types get unboxed automatically, so it's the same as writing `a.intValue() <= b.intValue()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - a whole ratsnest of implications has been unveiled.

What is happening is that for the operators '>=', '<=', '<', and '>' the compiler already knows that they can only be executed on primitive types, so automatically an unboxing will happen (convert the Object type to a primitive type). That is why those operators can be executed on Integer instances.

*However*, when using '==' or '!=', the compiler knows it can compare instances directly, basically comparing wether or not two variables are referencing the same object or not. It is not a true integer comparison at all.

As a matter of fact, this will return false:

```
System.out.println("Test == :"+(new Integer(1000) == new Integer(1000)));
System.out.println("Test == :"+(new Integer(100) == new Integer(100)));
```

These most likely will return false:

```
System.out.println("Test == :"+((Integer)1000 == (Integer)1000));
System.out.println("Test == :"+(Integer.valueOf(1000) == Integer.valueOf(1000)));
```

Although these most likely will return true:

```
System.out.println("Test == :"+((Integer)100 == (Integer)100));
System.out.println("Test == :"+(Integer.valueOf(100) == Integer.valueOf(100)));
```

'Most likely' because it is going to be implementation specific, and even can be controlled by parameters.

due to the fact that integer objects with values in the range -127..128 are being interned when using the `Integer.valueOf(int)` static factory method. See [a more elaborate explenation](https://thecodebutchery.com/2013/02/25/java-long-and-integer-objects-interning-and-comparison-methods/).

But please never assume that this will ever work, and always use the `Comparable` interface, `.equals(...)`, or do the unboxing.

For reference, also review these articles:

- [Why aren't Integers cached in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277881/why-arent-integers-cached-in-java)
- [Using == operator in Java to compare wrapper objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149959/using-operator-in-java-to-compare-wrapper-objects)

Comment: Can only Wrappers be unboxed? Also, == and != is not part of my question though since between objects (including wrappers) it means reference (in) equality

Comment: There is a duality between primitive types and their boxed type (wrapper). You cannot extend that on other wrappers, because you can also not further define primitive types.

Comment: If you use the constructor (instead of `Integer.valueOf`) you don't get the cached value. So both of your examples will always print false.

Comment: @Bubletan corrected based on your input - thx.