# Integer caching in Java with new operator

Tags: java, instance, equals

In the below class I have tried to compare the wrapper class with the primitive but the results are different.

I have checked the following links [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277881/why-arent-integers-cached-in-java):

> The more interesting question is why `new Object();` should be required to create a unique instance every time? i. e. why is `new Object();` not allowed to cache? The answer is the `wait(...)` and `notify(...)` calls. Caching new `Object()`s would incorrectly cause threads to synchronize with each other when they shouldn't.

If there is a new object then how are `a` and `c` equal?

If `b` is equal to `c` and `c` is equal to `a`, then `a` should be equal to `b`. But in following case I got `a != c`.

Please explain.

```
class WrapperCompare {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Integer a = new Integer(10);    
        Integer b = 10; 
        int c=10;
        System.out.println(b==c);       //true
        System.out.println(a==b);       //false
        System.out.println(a==c);       //true
    }
}
```

Update: 
By referring to this link [Integer caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130311/weird-integer-boxing-in-java).

> Basically, the Integer class keeps a cache of Integer instances in the range of -128 to 127, and all autoboxing, literals and uses of Integer.valueOf() will return instances from that cache for the range it covers.

So in this case all statements should be true.

Comment: Note that the constructor is **deprecated** and should not be used. Instead use `valueOf`.

Comment: All but `a==b` here aren't comparing objects.

Comment: @Zabuza that's incorrect. `new` *always* returns a new instance. You only get the cached instances via `valueOf` (implicitly or explicitly).

Comment: The statement `Integer b = 10;` is equivalent to `Integer b = Integer.valueOf(10);` (and not `Integer b = new Integer(10);`)

Comment: Good question, good answer, good comments. Good job everyone! :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Explanation

When you compare `Integer` vs `int` with `==`, it needs to convert the `Integer` to an `int`. This is called **unboxing**.

See [JLS§5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8):

> If `r` is a reference of type `Integer`, then **unboxing conversion** converts `r` into `r.intValue()`

At that point, you are comparing `int` vs `int`. And primitives have no notion of instances, they all refer to the **same value**. As such, the result is `true`.

So the actual code you have is

```
a.intValue() == c
```

leading to a comparison of `10 == 10`, both `int` values, no `Integer` instances anymore.

You can see that `new Integer(...)` indeed creates new instances, when you compare `Integer` vs `Integer`. You did that in `a == b`.

---

### Note

The constructor `new Integer(...)` is **deprecated**. You should instead use `Integer#valueOf`, it is potentially faster and also uses an internal cache. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)):

> Returns an `Integer` instance representing the specified `int` value. If a new Integer instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor `Integer(int)`, as this method is likely to yield **significantly better** space and time **performance** by **caching** frequently requested values. This method will always cache values in the range `-128` to `127`, inclusive, and **may cache other values** outside of this range.

The caching is important to note here, since it yields to `==` being true again (for cached values):

```
Integer first = Integer.valueOf(10);
Integer second = Integer.valueOf(10);
System.out.println(first == second); // true
```

The caching is guaranteed for values between `-128` and `+127`, but may also be used for others.

Also note that your `b` actually comes out of the cache, since

```
Integer b = 10;
// same as
Integer b = Integer.valueOf(10);
// and not
Integer b = new Integer(10);
```

So **boxing** goes through `Integer`s cache (see [JLS§5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)).

Comment: “it is much faster” is a too strong claim. As the documentation says, “this method is *likely* to yield significantly better space and time performance”, in other words, it enables potential optimizations, whether they exist, is implementation dependent.