# Caching of boxed values in Java

Tags: java, autoboxing

I have following code:

```
Integer first = new Integer(4);
Integer second = new Integer(4);
System.out.println(first == second);
Integer third = 4;
System.out.println(first == third);
System.out.println(second == third);
```

As 4 falls between -128 to 127, I expect that Integer object wrapping 4 is cached once its created first time, and then its returned for other boxing statements, and so '==' check must return true. But its always false for above three cases.

Why is it so?

Comment: The `new` keyword _always_ constructs a _new_ object. To make use of the cache you either have to rely on auto-boxing or manually use `Integer#valueOf(int)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because these assignments are made using the '`new`' keyword, they are new instances created, and not picked up from the pool. Also note that the integer pool contains only integers from -128 to 127. For higher values, pool do not come to play.

```
Integer third = 4;
Integer fourth = 4;
Integer fifth = 130;
Integer sixth = 130;
Integer seventh = 127;
Integer eighth = 127;
System.out.println(third == fourth); // 4==4 Return true
System.out.println(fifth == sixth); // 130==130 Returns false
System.out.println(seventh == eighth); // 127==127 Returns true
```

**edit**
As rightly mentioned in the comment, from Java 1.6 auto box limit can be extended by using `-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=new_limit` from command line.

Comment: *"Also note that the integer pool contains only integers from -128 to 127."* - By default.  There is an obscure JVM command line option that can change the default: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30220901/139985

Comment: @StephenC Thank you for that info. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For reference types **(Integer)**, use `equals` to compare the values of two Integers and `==` to compare whether the references point to the same object (i.e., share the same address). In most cases, it's `equals` what you want and not `==`.

For primitive types (int), you have to use `==`, and it compares the values to two ints. (equals doesn't work because it's defined on objects only, which primitives are not by definition.)

In your question, you are using the `new Integer(3)` keywors, which creates a new object in the pool. Hence, object references are not the same.

See [this link](https://www.quora.com/Can-we-compare-integers-by-using-equals-in-Java) for more information.