# Why do i get an infinite loop when I use int instead of Integer in Java?

Tags: java, types

I am trying to solve the problem [1438. Longest Continuous Subarray With Absolute Diff Less Than or Equal to Limit](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-continuous-subarray-with-absolute-diff-less-than-or-equal-to-limit/). I got the logic but there was a very weird problem due to which I had to pull my hair for more than two hours.

Here is the code :-

```
class Solution {
    public int longestSubarray(int[] nums, int limit) {
        Deque<Integer> maxDeque = new LinkedList();
        Deque<Integer> minDeque = new LinkedList();
        Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList();

        int maxLength = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            Integer temp = nums[i];
            //int temp = nums[i]; //If I uncomment this line and comment the above line, the code does not work.
            queue.offer(temp);

            while (!maxDeque.isEmpty() && maxDeque.peekLast() < temp) {
                maxDeque.removeLast();
            }

            while (!minDeque.isEmpty() && minDeque.peekLast() > temp) {
                minDeque.removeLast();
            }

            maxDeque.offerLast(temp);
            minDeque.offerLast(temp);

            while (maxDeque.peekFirst() - minDeque.peekFirst() > limit) {
                if (queue.peek() == maxDeque.peekFirst()) {
                    maxDeque.pollFirst();
                }

                if (queue.peek() == minDeque.peekFirst()) {
                    minDeque.pollFirst();
                }

                queue.poll();
            }

            
            maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, queue.size());

        }

        return maxLength;
    }
}
```

You see when I put an integer into each of the queues, the code runs fine but when I put an int into the three queues, I get a TLE. So, in the below code, if temp is `Integer`, the code passes but when temp is `int`, it gives a TLE. Can someone please explain what is going on ?

Comment: The `int` version does an extra 2 boxing operations per iteration, but I wouldn't expect it to have such an impact.

Comment: I would expect an NPE to be thrown (and not swallowed elsewheres), but to double check: there are no values within `nums` that are `null`, correct? (Verify this in the code itself, not just by assumption)

Comment: No. I checked the values are not null. You can verify yourself by running the code in the leetcode IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `==` to compare `Integer`s. It only works when you pre-box `temp` because of reference equality. Use `.equals()` instead:

```
if (queue.peek().equals(maxDeque.peekFirst())) {
    maxDeque.pollFirst();
}

if (queue.peek().equals(minDeque.peekFirst())) {
    minDeque.pollFirst();
}
```

Comment: That's a good catch! I think it should only work for small numbers, because of interning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277881/why-arent-integers-cached-in-java