# Why two objects of employee are not equal?

Tags: java, object, collections

I have created an Employee class having name and employeeNo . 
I am overriding equals and hashcode method.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       final Employee other = (Employee) obj;

 if (this.employeeNo == other.employeeNo && this.name.equals(other.name)) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
    }

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 53 * hash + (this.name != null ? this.name.hashCode() : 0);
    hash = 53 * hash + this.employeeNo;
    return hash;
}
```

My test class

```
Employee p = new Employee();
        p.setName("v");
        p.setEmployeeNo(1);

        Employee p1 = new Employee();
        p.setName("v");
        p.setEmployeeNo(1);

        System.out.println(p==p1); // Print false . why?
```

Comment: Your `equals`methods should verify that obj is not `null` before the cast.

Comment: `==` compares references, it doesn't call a method like `equals`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
System.out.println(p==p1);
```

does not implicitly call `equals(`. It compares the references which are different here. Use:

```
System.out.println(p.equals(p1));
```

instead.

Also:

```
Employee p1 = new Employee();
p.setName("v");
p.setEmployeeNo(1);
```

uses `p`, where `p1` should be used.

Comment: Crap..!! I did a blunder.. :(

Comment: @Thinker I suggest editing your comment to read "crap" instead.

Comment: And also i am trying to print the hashcode of p and p1. They both are different . They should be same right?

Comment: @Thinker Found it. You set the fields of `p` twice and never set `p1`.

Comment: you are genius. Thanks. I learnt new thing today. Never do copy paster

Answer (score 0):

The error maybe in this line:

```
if (this.employeeNo == other.employeeNo && this.name.equals(other.name)) {
    return true;
}
```

This condition will only become `true`, if booth `employeeNr` are the same. If `employeeNr` is of type `Integer` and not `int`.

If is false becuase equals() is not calles.

a==b will check iif the objects are the same

e.equals(b) will call the equals()

Comment: Integer a = new Integer(1); Integer b = new Integer(1); a==b will become true?

Comment: No.That is the mistake i did.

Comment: @hexafraction You're wrong, you should read this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428774/why-java-does-not-see-that-integers-are-equal