# Is x in the Array Stack. I do not know why my code does not work. As it returns false even if I give x which is in the ArrayStack

Tags: java

```
public static boolean xIn(Stack<Integer> st, int x) throws Exception {

    int result;
    int size = st.getSize();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        result = st.pop();
        if (x == result) {
            return true;
        }
        st.push(result);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: ???? My code is logically incorrect. It seems fine to me. You need to have ArrayStack and Stack Interface plus methods for this)

Comment: Don't compare objects with ==. Also, popping then pushing in a loop will always compare the same element, that is at top of the stack. Why don't you use Stack.contains()?

Comment: You shouldn't use == to compare objects, use .equals or better yet, use stack.contains.

Comment: If you're implementing your own Stack, than this method should be part of the Stack class itself. That way, you just need to iterate over the elements of the stack instead of popping and pushing.

Comment: Stack class offers an iterator, So simpliest solution would be `boolean xIn(Stack<Integer> st, int x){for(Integer i : st)if(i.equals(x))return true;return false;}`

Comment: @ArcticLord if the OP uses an actual java.util.Stack, then it also has a contains() method. No need to iterate.

Answer (score 4):

When you `pop` an item from a stack, you remove it from the **top**. And when you `push` an item to a stack, you put it on the **top**.

You are continually checking only the **first** element on the **top** of the stack.

Also, another thing, shouldn't you `push` the element back to the stack just before you `return true`?

Answer (score 0):

You always check the last element, popping it and then pushing it again.
Use e.g. an enhanced for loop to iterate the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
public static boolean xIn(Stack<Integer> st, int x){

    int result;
    int size = st.getSize();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (x == st.get(i)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, I advice you to have a look here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html
There is alot of predefined methods that do your job such as:
search(obj o)
contains(obj o)

Comment: I assumed he using java.util.stack which inherited from java.util.vector which in turns has the get(int index) method

Comment: in that case, he should use Stack.contains().

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static boolean xIn(Stack<Integer> st, int x) throws Exception {
   Stack<Integer> temp=new ArrayStack();
    int result;
    int size = st.getSize();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        result = st.pop();
        if (x == result) {
            return true;
        }
        temp.push(result);
    }
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
         result=temp.pop();
         st.push(result);
     }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, `temp` stack won't help you, since you `return` from the function before you push the elements back to the original stack. Instead of a `return`, use a boolean variable which you return at the end.

Comment: Pretend you find x, you will return after having removed nearly all of st. You should have probably edited your original question instead of posting a new answer. Also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428774/why-java-does-not-see-that-integers-are-equal) addresses a common pitfal with integers.