# How to check if an unset object has attributes

Tags: java, class, attributes

I'm trying to form a method to call on a object to check if it contains some of the attributes in the class

This is the code that I've tried so far

```
public class BoundingBox {

    public int x, y, width, height;

    public BoundingBox() {

    }

    public Integer getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(Integer x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public Integer getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(Integer Y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
        if (x == getX() & y == getY()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

However when I created the object with all attributes holding the value of 10 and tested it using object.contains(15,15), it does not return false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java the operator `&` can assume different meanings:

> - `&` : **Bitwise operator**
> - `&&` : **Logical operator**

In the if statement `if (x == getX() & y == getY()) {` you used the `&` **bitwise operator** instead of the `&&` **logical operator**. 
Plus there was a typo in the `setY` method and, as stated by @alvinalvord, comparing `int` with `Integer` can give unexpected results.

Change your code like this and it will work:

```
public class BoundingBox {

    public int x, y, width, height;

    public BoundingBox() {

    }

    public Integer getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(Integer x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public Integer getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(Integer y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
        return getX().equals(x) && getY().equals(y);
    }
}
```

---

### Alternative Code

Or, if there's no particular reason to keep the `Integer` variables, you can change the code like this:

```
public class BoundingBox {

    public int x, y, width, height;

    public BoundingBox(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
        return getX() == x && getY() == y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are there Integer arguments in the methods instead of just int, if the fileds are declared as int?

Comment: Well, he didn't speciefied if they're there for a reason or not, so I kept them. But for me personally, I don't think they're needed.

Comment: I've changed my code to this but I still get a false result on the method even when I input the correct x and y values. It only returns true for 0?

Comment: @hh_vv My guess is that `x` and `y` are not initialized correctly in the code. I've updated the alternate code. I've personally tested it and it works. Let me know if it solve the issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing int and Integer also has some problems [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428774/why-java-does-not-see-that-integers-are-equal). Best return int for your getters.

Comment: Right, I'm giving you credit in my answer for noting that.

Answer (score -1):

Your of test in contains is missing an ampersand, it should be && instead of &. Single ampersand is bitwise AND, not logical AND.

Answer (score -1):

Your `setY` method has a bug:

```
 public void setY(Integer Y) {
        this.y = y;
 }
```

Y is capital, that's why `this.y = y` does not work. This line of code makes no sense, that's why you get false when youc compare y in `contains()` method.
Change it to:

```
 public void setY(Integer y) {
            this.y = y;
 }
```

Comment: This doesn’t explain why his intended test returns true.

Comment: @Joe, his test always returns false, not true, (only if y is equal to 0 and this.x = x ); Bitwise & operator works in this case as the author expects.