# Java : The Map value comparison is failing to compare with the higher values. Why?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

**Why I'm getting only the message "a value is same" as an output ? Is it due to some auto-boxing ?**

Code :

```
 Map<Character, Integer> pMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Character, Integer> sMap = new HashMap<>();
    char c = 'a';
    pMap.put(c, 10);
    sMap.put(c, 10);
    if (sMap.get(c) == pMap.get(c)) {
        System.out.println(c + " value is same");
    }
    char d = 'b';
    pMap.put(d, 10000);
    sMap.put(d, 10000);
    if (sMap.get(d) == pMap.get(d)) {
        System.out.println(d + " value is same");
    }
```

Comment: use `equals` to compare `Integers` higher than 127.

Comment: It's because Java caches the Integer instances from -127 to 128

Comment: All java wrapper classes have `equals()` method implemented in it. So if you want to compare `Integer` object then always use `equals` method.

Comment: Refer to this link for the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428774/why-java-does-not-see-that-integers-are-equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Integer`s are object types so for comparing them you should use [`Integer::equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). For `Integer`s in range [-128 , 127] there is a special Integer pool. When you `put` your `int` values in the map, they are boxed to `Integer` - hence same values in your map, between `[-128 , 127]`, will be references to same values in `Integer` pool. That is why `==` for `[-128 , 127]` values returns true. But generally you should use `equals` here or perform unboxing explicitly.

Comment: Use `equals` or enforce `int` comparison, e.g. `sMap.get(d) == (int)pMap.get(d)`.