Why does == work for small integers but not for larger ones in Java?
I've noticed a peculiar behavior in Java when comparing Integer objects using the == operator. Specifically, it seems to work as expected for small integer values but fails for larger ones. Here is an example to illustrate the issue:
Integer a = 127;
Integer b = 127;
System.out.println(a == b); // Output: true

Integer c = 128;
Integer d = 128;
System.out.println(c == d); // Output: false

In the first comparison    (a == b), the result is     true, but in the second comparison     (c == d), the result is     false. From what I understand, == should check for reference equality, so why does it behave differently for these values?
Could someone explain why this discrepancy occurs and how Java handles integer comparisons under the hood? Additionally, what is the best practice for comparing Integer values in Java to avoid such pitfalls?

The way to avoid these pitfalls is to NOT use == to compare Integer objects.  Ever.  The way to check that you are not making that mistake it is to use a "bug checker"; e.g. SonarCube, PMD, FindBugs, and so on.  But you should search for answers before you ask questions.  This question and similar ones have been asked and answered many times before.  See the duplinks for some of them.  (And read them!!)

Java caches Integer objects for all integer values in the range of -128 to 127.
when you create integer out of this range it create new object for store data but has different reference, then you try to compare using '==' it shows as false due to two separate object references ( Even it has same value )
This is done for performance reasons, to save memory and improve performance.
If you look into concept of integer caching you can learn more about this

@SasankaWeerakoon - Yea.  But we would prefer it if the OP read the duplinks.

Yes, Also found lots of similar questions regarding this eg: Q01 and also [Q02] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428774/why-java-does-not-see-that-integers-are-equal)

@StephenC well received .

@YAS-SER you should have completed the [tour]: "Don't ask about... * Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"

@SasankaWeerakoon On top of that the range that you give as -128 to 127 is configurable. So tomorrow or on a different Java installation it may be different.
